# c++ vector allocation question

Tags: c++

I am trying to push a vector into a list.
My question is how do you allocate a new vector after you push it into the list.

```
std::list<std::vector<int>> foolist;
std::vector<int> foo;

while(1)
{
  foolist.push_back(foo);
  foo = new std::vector<int>;
}
```

The above code doesn't work.
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’

This is for a crypto class. I need to generate a bunch of hashes and check for collisions. So yes, in some ways I will run out of memory if I can't find a collision. (Collision - finding a input that will generate the same hash).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write Java with C++ syntax.

Comment: That isn't the exact and complete error message you are getting from the compiler. Always provide the diagnostics you get exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to allocate a new vector. `std::list` will actually hold a copy of what you pushed, so you can just do:

```
std::list<std::vector<int>> foolist;
std::vector<int> foo;

for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  foolist.push_back(foo);
```

Chances are this whole thing is a mistake though -- I'd consider almost all use of `std::list` questionable, and this one even more so than most others.

Comment: This is for a crypto class.  I need to generate a bunch of hashes and check for collisions.  So yes, in some ways I will run out of memory if I can't find a collision.  (Collision - finding a input that will generate the same hash).

Comment: @user103052: In that case, I'd probably put them into a trie. Less space and faster lookup.

Comment: So what I push into the list is automatically allocated??